# How to route in Mule ESB using request path

Tags: java, xml, mule

Hello I am trying to add a router in flow, so that I can re-use my code and to avoid duplication.

I normally do a flow for each request path for example :

HTTP LISTENER = localhost:8080/mule1
HTTP LISTENER = localhost:8080/mule2

I would like to know if it's possible to route via the Router/Choice connector using the request path. I am not able to do it as it tells me there is only a listener for /

Here's my code :

```
<flow name="Tickets">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.listener.path']" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.request.path' == &quot;/getTicketByTicketCode&quot;]">
                <set-payload value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.ticketcode]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
                <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
                    <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[def writer = new StringWriter() 
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)
xml.mkp.xmlDeclaration(version: "1.0", encoding: "UTF-8")
xml.GetTicketByCode(xmlns: 'http://tempuri.org/') { 
  code(payload)
} 
result = writer.toString() ]]></scripting:script>
                </scripting:component>
                <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="GetTicketByCode" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
            </when>
            <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.request.path' == &quot;/validateTickets&quot;]">
                <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
                    <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[]]></scripting:script>
                </scripting:component>
                <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="ValidateTicket" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
            </when>
        </choice>
        <mulexml:xslt-transformer xsl-file="removeattributes.xsl" maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" doc:name="XSLT"/>
        <json:xml-to-json-transformer doc:name="XML to JSON"/>
    </flow>


INFO  2015-05-26 09:25:40,303 [[billeterie].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpListenerRegistry: No listener found for request: (GET)/getTicketByTicketCode
INFO  2015-05-26 09:25:40,303 [[billeterie].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpListenerRegistry: Available listeners are: [(*)/]
```

Is there a way to make this work? Or is the only way is to add another queryParam that would act like the path. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `path="/*"` and I have modified your flow as following:-

```
<flow name="Tickets">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/*" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.listener.path']" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.request.path'.contains('/getTicketByTicketCode')]">
                 <logger message="getTicketByTicketCode flow" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                 <set-payload value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.ticketcode]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
                <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
                    <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[def writer = new StringWriter() 
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)
xml.mkp.xmlDeclaration(version: "1.0", encoding: "UTF-8")
xml.GetTicketByCode(xmlns: 'http://tempuri.org/') { 
  code(payload)
} 
result = writer.toString() ]]></scripting:script>
                </scripting:component>
                <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="GetTicketByCode" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>

            </when>
            <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.request.path'.contains('/validateTickets')]">
                 <logger message="validateTickets flow" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/> 
                  <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
                    <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[]]></scripting:script>
                </scripting:component>
                <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="ValidateTicket" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
               <logger message="Other than this url " level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/> 

            </otherwise>

           <mulexml:xslt-transformer xsl-file="removeattributes.xsl" maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" doc:name="XSLT"/>
        <json:xml-to-json-transformer doc:name="XML to JSON"/> 
        </choice>

    </flow>
```

Now if your url contain **getTicketByTicketCode** then it will go to the first flow, and if it contains **validateTickets** it will go to second flow....

or else if it doesn't have any of these 2 it will print the logger in **otherwise** condition

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try that... Thanks for the answer it works perfectly.

Comment: I would really suggest using APIKit: https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/APIkit